# SqlAlchemy "synthetic" related models

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to model the attachment of arbitrary data types to contacts to model a simple CRM:

```py
class Person(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    first_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=True)


class Field(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    type = Column(String(length=32), nullable=False, index=True)
    name = Column(String(length=64), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "type", "name", name="_name_type_uc"
        ),
    )


class FieldValue(Base):
    value = Column(String)

    field_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("field.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True
    )
    field = relationship("Field", backref="fields")

    person_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True
    )
    person = relationship("Person", backref="values")
```

For a given Field, we have Persons whose FieldValues can be represented by a value, where missing (field_id, person_id) pairs represent null values:

```
 Person1 Person2 Person3
|-------|-------|-------|
|  "hi" |  null | "bye" | Field(type="string", name="greeting")
|  "1"  |  "2"  |  null | Field(type="integer", name="website_visits")
|-------|-------|-------|
```

For all the non-null elements of the list, there is a FieldValue row, for all the null elements of the list, there is not a FieldValue row.

For a given Person, I'd like to have a related view based on the SQL tables described above that looks roughly like this:

```py
class SyntheticPersonProperty:
    field_id := id from Field.id
    person_id := id from Person.id
    name := name from Field.name
    type := type from Field.type
    value := nullable value from FieldValue: null if no (field_id, person_id) match is found in FieldValue

class Person(Base):
    ... fields described in Person above
    properties: List[SyntheticPersonProperty]
```

I understand that SqlAlchemy has support for views, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that support in this case. Any help would be appreciated.